# If the median from one vertex of a triangle is equal to the altitude from another vertex, then must the triangle be equilateral?

Tags: geometry

[image: Triangle]
$|BE|=|AD|$
and $|BD|=|DC|$

I know that in an equilateral triangle all auxiliary elements are equal. That is,

$$n_a=n_b=n_c=h_a=h_b=h_c=m_a=m_b=m_c$$

$m$, $n$, $h$ being median, angle bisector, and altitude respectively.

> If $m_a=h_b$ in a triangle, does it imply that the triangle is equilateral (see picture)?

Comment: Consider right triangle $\triangle ABC$ with right angle at $C$, such that $|BC|=2p$ and $|AC|=p\sqrt{3}$. Note that $\overline{BC}$ is the altitude from $B$, and that it is congruent to the median from $A$, yet the triangle is not equilateral (or even isosceles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the $A$-vertex lies on the red curve we have $m_a=h_b$:

[image]

The construction is pretty straightforward: we draw a circle $\Gamma_1$ centered at the midpoint of $BC$ with radius $\ell$, a circle $\Gamma_2$ centered at $B$ with radius $\ell$, a tangent $\tau$ from $C$ to $\Gamma_2$. $A=\Gamma_1\cap\tau$ solves the problem.

The red curve is an arc of the circle which goes through $M,C$ and the point $D$ on the perpendicular to $BC$ through $C$, such that $DM=BC$.

In particular $m_a=h_b$ implies that $AV=MC$, where $V$ is the "missing vertex" of an equilateral triangle built on $MC$, such that $V$ and $A$ lie on the same half-plane with respect to $BC$. Why? Because if $N$ is the projection of $M$ on $AC$, then $MN=\frac{1}{2}BT=\frac{1}{2}AM$ implies $\widehat{MAN}=\widehat{MAC}=30^{\circ}$, hence $A$ lies on a circle centered at $V$ through $M$ and $C$.